# How can control the order of events when attaching content script files to a tab

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The Firefox add-on I'm developing has settings stored in simple-storage which are for a custom jQueryUI plugin. This plugin is used in many systems and other browser extensions, so I'm hesitant to do any Firefox specific changes.

How can I load the settings into a loader js that is accessible by the main plugin? I tried using this code, but the values created in the loader.js no longer exists when plugin.js is loaded.

```
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){
   var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url('loader.js')
   });

   worker.port.emit('load', settings);

   tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: self.data.url('plugin.js')
    });
});
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the scripts separately, they won't be loaded into the same environment and won't share variables. `contentScriptFile` accepts an array, so do this:

```
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){
   var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: [ self.data.url('loader.js'), self.data.url('plugin.js')]
   });

   worker.port.emit('load', settings);
});
```